# UWP Pivot control clears its content when I navigate to a other page and goes back

Tags: c#, uwp, pivotitem

I have a UWP page with a pivot control. I am using MVVM pattern where the `ItemsSource` property of the pivot is bound to an observable collection of my viewmodels. I am using the `ItemTemplateSelector` of the pivot to select the appropriate DataTemplate for each view model based on the Pivot `SelectedItem` which in turn is bound to the selected view model.

Here the is XAML that I am using:

```
<Pivot  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Margin="10" 
IsHeaderItemsCarouselEnabled="False" 
ItemsSource ="{x:Bind MainPageViewModel.EditViewModels}"  
SelectedItem="{x:Bind MainPageViewModel.SelectedEntityViewModel,Mode=TwoWay}"
ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource DetailViewTemplateSelector}"  >
<Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewModel:DetailViewModelBase">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding TabHeader,Mode=OneWay}" FontSize="12" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
       </StackPanel >
    </DataTemplate>
</Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
</Pivot>
```

Within the same page, I have a navigation view where the navigationItem click event creates a new view model based on the selected item and adds it to the observable collection `MainPageViewModel.EditViewModels` and set the `SelectedViewModel` to the newly created one.

The application works fine as expected working arround implicit DataTemplate that is in WPF and missing in UWP. The only problem I am having is that when I navigate from the page that contains the Pivot controls and comes back, then all the Pivot Items are cleared and not showed.

I have set in the page constructor `this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Required` and did not override the `NavigateTo` method.

If I set my usercontrols within the Pivot Items directly without using `DataTemplate` selector then the Pivot items are maintained when I come back to the page. The pivot items are cleared only when I use the `ItemTemplateSelector`.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. I spent more than four days on it without being able to figure out the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I created a ItemTemplateSelector and when I clicked the navigationViewItem, I created a new viewmodel based on the selected item, added it to the EditViewModels and set the SelectedViewModel to the new viewmodel. I also set the NavigationCacheMode to Required. After that, When I came back to the page which contanins the Pivot, the contents displayed well and were not cleared. I can't reproduce this issue. So can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: have you enable the cache mode in page constructor ?? `this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Enabled`

Comment: Ketan: yes I have this.NavigationCacheMode = Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.NavigationCacheMode.Required in the constructor

Comment: here is a link for the sample code: [link](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AobOIzC5dC6rhaIyL7NpJuXLtTUjFQ?e=4Pb06z). Each click on the list view will open a pivot item. Later, when you click the navigate button (top left corner) and then backarrow, then the pivotitems are cleared

Comment: Neil: I don´t know if this helps, but I am using windows 10 built 1903 with visual studio version 16.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at your sample and noticed your `MainCrudPage_Loaded` method is **always** creating a new instance of `TabelaWindow_ViewModel` and assigning it to your `MainPageViewModel` property and `DataContext`:

```cs
private async void MainCrudPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MainPageViewModel = new TabelaWindow_ViewModel();// Sinergia.UWP.BootStrap.AppContainer.Container.Resolve<Sinergia.UWP.ViewModels.Window.TabelaWindow_ViewModel>();
    //await MainPageViewModel.LoadAsync();
    DataContext = MainPageViewModel;
    //naviView.DataContext = MainPageViewModel.NavigationVM;
    this.Bindings.Update();
}
```

As the `Loaded` event is always called, regardless of whether the `Page` is cached, you are effectively overwriting the cached data View Model data when you navigate back. As the page cache reuses the existing instance of `MainPage`, the `MainPageViewModel` and `DataContext` are already populated when you return to the page (you can check this by putting a breakpoint at the beginning of the `MainCrudPage_Loaded` method.

If you update your sample to the following, you will see what I mean:

```cs
private async void MainCrudPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (null == DataContext)
    {
        MainPageViewModel = new TabelaWindow_ViewModel();// Sinergia.UWP.BootStrap.AppContainer.Container.Resolve<Sinergia.UWP.ViewModels.Window.TabelaWindow_ViewModel>();
        //await MainPageViewModel.LoadAsync();
        DataContext = MainPageViewModel;
    }
    //naviView.DataContext = MainPageViewModel.NavigationVM;
    this.Bindings.Update();
}
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot Daren and all who commented my question. This helped a lot and saved my week.